# Angular and Nestjs: It's impossible to upload files

Tags: angular, file-upload, nestjs

I want to upload files with Angular 16 and the latest version of Nestjs, but although it is possible to upload the file **with Postman** when I try to do it with Angular, it is not possible to do so. I have tried every means to do it, I have even tried just sending flat data based on **application/json**, and the api end-point does respond positively, but when I try to configure the **multipart/form-data** the end-point does not respond.

```js
uploadFile(file: File, title: string) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  });
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, title);

  return this.http.post(`http://localhost:4110/upload`, formData, { headers });
}
```

And my server code is:

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', { dest: 'public/files' }))
upload(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File): void {
  console.log(file)
}
```

The request remains pending for almost 30 seconds or a little more, after that it fails with the following status: **(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED**

What else do I need to configure in Angular to be able to receive the file?